# No 3rd and 4th gear selection

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, polo

Good day. I drive a 2004/2005 VW Polo Classic 1.9 TDI 5 speed. My Polo recently started with an oil leak on the gearbox after I had the CV joints replaced. On my way to the auto parts shop to buy gearbox oil, 3rd and 4th gear struggled to engage and made a grinding sound. I did not force the car into gear but decided to pull over and stop. I then pulled away again and when I wanted to try and select 3rd and 4th gear, it was as if the were never there. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Was there a leak or any trouble shifting before the CV joints were replaced? If "No", how recently after the work was complete did these problems start?

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities:

1. the selection mechanism at the gear lever
2. one of the cables or links has stretched, broken or disconnected
3. the selectors and interlocking detents in the gearbox are out of
   alignment
4. the synchromesh assembly for 3&4 is damaged, seized or breaking up.
   Further investigation needed